# Select part of the string using selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I want to select part of the title of the website.

[image]

after inspecting the title, the html code of the website looks like this:

[image]

and i want to select only the "2014 Ram 1500" part. For this i wrote the following code:

```
# car name
            try:
                temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="react"]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/h1[1]/text()[2]').text
                data.append(temp)
            except:
                data.append('')
```

but i only getting a empty string(' '). I am using **selenium** for automation and copying the full Xpath of "2014 Ram 1500" in the code. What im doing wrong? And how i can i only select "2014 Ram 1500" part from the whole title?

Answer (score 1):

The text are in new line, you can split the string based on `\n` and from string array we could extract the first element.

```
try:
    temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react"]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/h1[1]').text
    a = temp.split('\n')[1]
    print(a)
    data.append(a)
except:
    data.append('')
```

Comment: dont know why this Xpath is not working. I had to use h1 header Xpath

Comment: You originally had this `//*[@id="react"]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/h1[1]/text()[2]` and by seeing it for the first time I knew it is wrong so I have given you this `//*[@id="react"]/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/h1[1]`. Well I could have given you more optimize locator, but no I won't.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote the below code and it actually worked. This time i copied the Xpath from h1 header and converted it in text. Then using slicing i got exactly what i wanted. Though i am not sure it is best practise or not:

```
# car name
            try:
                temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div/h1[1]').text
                temp = temp.split()[1:-2]
                temp = " ".join(e for e in temp)
                data.append(temp)
            except:
                data.append('')
```